# How to input data into datapool from xml file in rational functional tester?

Tags: automated-testing, rft

How to input data into datapool from xml file in rational functional tester? I want the user input file to be an xml file and this xml file should be used to feed information for data pool in rft.

Answer (score 0):

The RFT datapool can be created from a CSV file but not from an XML file. However, searching for "Convert XML file to a CSV file" on the internet yielded many results.

Alternatively, you could develop/use a library to read from an XML file and insert the calls into a standard RFT Java test script.